# Mysql: how to merge two table with same low and different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. They have same rows and different columns. For example,

Table 1

id / fruit 
1 / apple 
2 / grape 
3 / banana

Table 2

id / price / city 
1 / 100 / Newyork
2 / 200 / LA
3 / 150 / DC

How can I merge above two tables and create new table?

It means, I expect this result

id / fruit / price / city 
1 / apple / 100 / Newyork 
2 / grape / 200 / LA 
3 / banana / 150 / DC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inner join`

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.fruit,t2.price,t2.city FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to [create a View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) with a join.  In your example, the syntax would be:

```
CREATE VIEW fruitPriceView AS
SELECT fruit.id 'id', fruit.fruit 'fruit', city.price 'price', city.city 'city'
from tableone fruit
join tabletwo city
on fruit.id = city.id;
```

Then you could just select what you want from the view:

```
SELECT * FROM fruitPriceView;
```